# What's the correct interval of convergence for $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{n2^n} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

> What's the correct interval of convergence for this series?
> $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x+1)^n}{n2^n} $$

After using the ratio test, I found that the limit approached $\frac{1}{2}$, and found that the endpoints were $-3$ and $1$.

- I plugged in $1$ and simplified the fraction to $\frac{1}{n}$, which diverges, so it is not included in the interval.
- For $-3$, I believe it simplifies to an alternating series $(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}$, which converges by the alternating series test.

So, I think the answer is $[-3,1)$ for the Interval of Convergence, is that right?

Comment: please always include your attempt. how did you get to that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

We can also do a root test to find the radius of convergence.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{x+1}{2\cdot n^\frac1n}\right|=\frac{|x+1|}{2}$$

Hence $r=2$.

You have also verified the boundary correctly.